# Will Allah reward a person for just gaining Islamic knowledge?

Tags: sharia, reward

Suppose a person studying how to give dawah to non-Muslims. but he couldn't give dawah to much non muslims. compare to how much he had learn. or he died after learning.

**So if a person gained many Islamic knowledge but couldn't implement that knowledge much because of various things.**

**Will Allah reward him for gaining those knowledge and for his efforts?**

Answer (score 1):

INSHA'ALLAH, THE PERSON WILL GET THE FULL REWARD.

Everything depends on intention. (Inna'mal amalu bin'niyat)
- Hadith

Answer (score 0):

Assalamualaikum,

Gaining knowledge is one of the best acts of worship a Muslim can do.

> **وَمَنْ سَلَكَ طَرِيقًا يَلْتَمِسُ فِيهِ عِلْمًا سَهَّلَ اللَّهُ لَهُ
> بِهِ طَرِيقًا إِلَى الْجَنَّةِ وَمَا اجْتَمَعَ قَوْمٌ فِي بَيْتٍ مِنْ
> بُيُوتِ اللَّهِ يَتْلُونَ كِتَابَ اللَّهِ وَيَتَدَارَسُونَهُ
> بَيْنَهُمْ إِلاَّ نَزَلَتْ عَلَيْهِمُ السَّكِينَةُ وَغَشِيَتْهُمُ
> الرَّحْمَةُ وَحَفَّتْهُمُ الْمَلاَئِكَةُ وَذَكَرَهُمُ اللَّهُ فِيمَنْ
> عِنْدَهُ**
>
> **Whoever travels a path in search of knowledge, Allah will make easy
> for him a path to Paradise. People do not gather in the houses of
> Allah, reciting the book of Allah and studying it together, but that
> tranquility will descend upon them, mercy will cover them, angels will
> surround them, and Allah will mention them to those near him.**
>
> Ṣaḥīḥ Muslim 2699

Gaining knowledge is a very good deed and sharing knowledge is also very good.

Uthman bin Affan reported: The Prophet, peace and blessings be upon him, said:

> **خَيْرُكُمْ مَنْ تَعَلَّمَ الْقُرْآنَ وَعَلَّمَهُ**
>
> **The best of you are those who learn the Quran and teach it.**
>
> Ṣaḥīḥ al-Bukhārī 5027

This hadith shows the importance of learning and teaching knowledge about Islam. So even conquering knowledge is a very good act of worship, but giving others knowledge is even better than that.

> **عن قتادة قُلْتُ يَا أُمَّ الْمُؤْمِنِينَ (عائشة) أَنْبِئِينِي عَنْ**
> **خُلُقِ رَسُولِ اللَّهِ صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ قَالَتْ**
> **أَلَسْتَ تَقْرَأُ الْقُرْآنَ قُلْتُ بَلَى قَالَتْ فَإِنَّ خُلُقَ**
> **نَبِيِّ اللَّهِ صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ كَانَ الْقُرْآنَ**
>
> **Abu Qatadah reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be
> upon him, said, “The best of what a man leaves behind are three: a
> righteous child who supplicates for him, an ongoing charity the reward
> of which reaches him, and knowledge that is acted upon after him.”**
>
> Ṣaḥīḥ Muslim 746

Hope you benefitted from this answer.

May Allah Grant You Jannah...